# When is the SoftReference itself reclaimed by GC?

Tags: garbage-collection, soft-references

When the object referenced by the SoftReference is reclaimed by the garbage collector, how does the garbage collector deal with the SoftReference itself?

Comment: Since a `SoftReference` only has an effect when it is itself reachable, the `SoftReference` is not reclaimed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JVM whenever there are no more references to the SoftReference object itself. References to SoftReference objects works "normal". Assuming the reference is strong.

```
String myString = "...";
SoftReference<String> softReference = new SoftReference<String>(myString);
// ... do some stuff

softReference = null; // no references to the SoftReference object itself so in the next garbage collector cycle, it will be garbaged collected.
```